# is it possible to do a Maven build using Build Forge?

Tags: maven, buildforge

Is it possible to do a Maven build using Build Forge? Currently we use Build Forge, ClearCase and ClearQuest with Ant scripts; would like to try a Maven build. Not sure if I can I have no test environment so don't want to mess up any thing and still learning all this stuff too

Answer (score 0):

Maven can be invoked from any build automation framework.

Create a buildforge step that invokes your Maven build as follows:

```
mvn -s /path/to/maven/settings/files/mysettings.xml clean package
```

Explicitly selecting the settings file is recommended as this enables you customise the Maven configuration for each project.

Project isolation can be further enhanced by ensuring that each project has it's own local repository location (See the "localRepository" parameter in the [settings file documentation](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html))